# consuming a post request(created locally) in android that return exception :null

Tags: android, jboss7.x, resteasy, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

1.I created in eclipse :

an EJB deployed in wildfly 10

a Web service that calls a method from the ejb session bean created that verify login and password 
I have two Tables Abonne (For users) and Compte(For accounts )

2.With that I created An android app that consume the post request whenever someone enter his login and password .

the app return : Exception:null

I'm really not familiar with web services requests and I didn't find the right documentation about how creating  a post request and how to consume it in the other hand .

in the server side:

1.this is my web service :

```
    @Stateless
    @Path("/login")

    public class RestWS {
    @EJB
    private ILocal metier ;
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String log(String ch)
    {
     String retour ;
     int success = metier.log(ch);
     if (success ==1)
     {
        retour ="Success";
     }
     else {
        retour="Fail";
     }
     return retour ;
     }
     }
```

2.This is the method I'm calling in my web service From my session Bean

```
    @Stateless
    public class EJBImplement implements ILocal 
    {

        @PersistenceContext
        EntityManager em;

        public int log (String ch )
        {
         int exit =0;
         Compte c ;
         String [] parts  =ch.trim().split("\\&");
         String part1 =parts[0];
         String part2=parts[1];
         String [] KeyValue1 = part1.trim().split("\\=");
         String key1=KeyValue1[0];
         String Value1=KeyValue1[1];
         String [] KeyValue2 = part2.trim().split("\\=");
         String key2=KeyValue2[0];
         String Value2=KeyValue2[1];
         String login =Value1.trim();
         String password=Value2.trim();
         Query q = em.createQuery
         ("Select c from Compte c 
          where c.login lik:x and c.password like :x1 ");
         q.setParameter("x", login);
         q.setParameter("x1", password);
         List<Compte>l=q.getResultList();
         if (!l.isEmpty()) {
         c =l.get(0);
        exit=1;
        }

        return exit;
        }

       }
```

In my Android App
1.This my asyntask in application in android where I consume my webService :

```
    public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){}

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.6:8080/RestRegister/login");

            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
            postDataParams.put("login",s1);
            postDataParams.put("password", s2);
            Log.e("params", postDataParams.toString());

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            String chaine =getPostDataString(postDataParams);
            Log.e("chaine", chaine);
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();

            }
            else {
                return new String("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

2.a method (called in Asyntask) that convert a JSON string to this Format :

param1=val1&param2=val2

```
public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

    while(itr.hasNext()){

        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);

        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL-Statement is faulty:

```
(Select c from Compte c 
      where c.login lik:x and c.password like :x1 ");
```

Replace "lik" by "like" and try again

Comment: Actually this is not the problem , when copying my code I don't know how the "e" in like was deleted . and still I have not found a solution to my problem yet .thank you .

Comment: Please post debug informations from request in the service, ejb.